# Active Admin turn off Index unless Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In an app I've inherited, we want to show a people admin interface using ActiveAdmin, however, we just have too many records in that table. I'd like to just use filtering only instead of showing paginated people. I mean, who's going to look through a list of thousands and thousands of records anyway? So, I was wondering if there's a way to disable paginating all people, but still having filters (search) work on index? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best solution, but I think it's work:

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      params.has_key?(:q) ? super : YourModel.none
    end
  end
end
```

or `params.has_key?(:q) ? end_of_association_chain : YourModel.none` if doesn't work with `super`

Comment: That's actually a good idea. However, and this is not an issue with your suggestion, but just the nature of the whole thing, the filtering seems sooo slow now instead of the page seeming slow. I guess it has to do the super slowness of loading up the data then filtering it. I think I'm going to have to just make a totally custom view for all of this.